# Why won't Chrome let me save style revisions?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I recently found out about the Chrome Developer Tools feature of being able to save style revisions back to the source file. Only problem is, mine doesn't seem to work. It's frustrating. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I use the magnifying glass to inspect an object, change its style in the 'elements' style panel on the right, click the name of the stylesheet which pulls up the 'sources' tab (I'm on Windows. I think that it pulls up 'resources' on Mac, unless maybe the video I was watching was just old and that's what it used to do), in this tab I look at the stylesheet and confirm that it has been changed. I right click on the stylesheet in the left panel where it shows the location of the stylesheet on my computer and view the revisions, I confirm that there was a revision made, I then right click again and go to 'save as' and save over the old stylesheet. I refresh the page. It goes back to the way it was before editing the style -.- Happens every time.

I have tried updating my Chrome and restarting my computer. Any other ideas at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was happening to me (I am using Windows 8, x64). In addition, having the .css file that I was working on open in another IDE would still cause it to ask me if it wanted to "reload the file? (changes detected)". However, after doing so, the changes still were not there.

I thought I should try closing all Chrome windows, then setting the Compatibility Mode to "Windows 7". This worked!

I actually thought of this fix when researching how to get the [**Tin.cr extension**](https://bitbucket.org/ryanackley/tincr) working, and it was suggested that this same method fixed Tin.cr. Not 100% sure that it's the same root problem, but apparently, [**it is caused by Chrome disabling NPAPI plugins on Windows 8**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tincr-for-chrome-devtools/q_cXN5l6kkU/ru_Jl3GWMl4J).

Anyways, I hope this works for you, provided you're on Windows 8 that is!